# MySQL Count Number of user records with "start" and "complete" entry on the same date?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I'm lost and perplexed here... I've been trying to got through a large table that collects all page impressions and actions for logged in users (with a known email address) and sort out the # of users who "started" and a # of users who "completed" a certain action in the same day, broken down by day, of course (in a date range I specify).

Here's a sample query I have to pull up all the records for a specific day that have BOTH "started" and "completed" flags:

```
SELECT t1.user_email, t1.event_name, t1.timestamp, t2.event_name, t2.timestamp
FROM click_tracking t1
LEFT JOIN click_tracking t2 ON t1.user_email = t2.user_email
WHERE t1.event_name = 'Started'
AND t2.event_name = 'Completed'
AND t1.timestamp <= '2021-05-17'
AND t1.timestamp >= '2021-05-16'  
AND t2.timestamp <= '2021-05-17'
AND t2.timestamp >= '2021-05-16'  
GROUP BY t1.user_email
ORDER BY t1.user_email ASC
```

Now, how do I extrapolate that query to 1) span a date range instead and 2) provide me with SUM or COUNT of records for each date showing both "started" and "completed" (those who have "started" on the same date), like this:

```
Date       |  Started  |  Completed
2021-05-17 |     88    |     14
2021-05-16 |     81    |     10
2021-05-15 |     66    |     12
....
```

And on top of that be optimized/fast enough to run on a large table (1M+ entries) without taking forever to crunch that.

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused.  If the users had both started and completed in the same day, why are the counts different?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because not every user that "starts" a process ends up "completing" it as a trackable goal. And only 10% of the users will end up being marked "completed" from those who "started" it. And some may start it multiple times in the same day, but only reach the end goal once, and end up being marked as "completed" as such. Think of it as tracking conversions on a specific goal - someone might start filling out a form, but not complete it. Then come back again later, start again, and complete it on the 2nd or 3rd attempt. So I need to know how many in total start vs. actually complete.

Comment: If they can start it and complete it multiple times in a day if your joining the table onto itself by only their email it will duplicate the hell out of the result.

Comment: Please update your question with `click_tracking` table structure and just enough rows of sample data to emulate the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This answers what I think is the original version of the question.

If you want started and completed by date, I would not start with your query.  Instead:

```
select date(timestamp), sum(event_name = 'Started') as num_started,
       sum(event_name = 'Completed') as num_completed
from click_tracking ct
group by date(timestamp);
```

If you want the number of users with start and complete on the same date, use two levels of aggregation:

```
select date, count(*) as num_emails,
       sum(num_started) as starts_on_date,
       sum(num_completed) as completes_on_date
from (select user_email, date(timestamp) as date,
             sum(event_name = 'Started') as num_started,
             sum(event_name = 'Completed') as num_completed
      from click_tracking
      group by user_email
     ) ct
where num_started > 0 and num_completed > 0
group by date
```

Comment: Hmm, I was looking for query #2, but see my edited question as your query is somehow showing some discrepancies in results, such as num_emails is some 10-15% smaller than num_started and num_completed number of records, even though I see GROUP BY user_email in the query that shouldn't cause those numbers to be any different. And num_started = num_completed for the most cases (with +/- 1 record as an error margin), so take a look at my edited request, that should track all "started" and those who have both "started" and "completed" on that specific date, and output them side by side. Thanks.

Comment: @CrazySerb . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.  This answers the question you actually asked here.

Comment: Just see my edit above. I am not just looking for the count of records where BOTH the "started" and "completed" is true, but two separate counts, 1) counting all those who "started" (regardless if they have "completed" or not), and 2) counting all those who BOTH "started" and "completed". That's all. Nothing else has been changed in terms of my requirements, I just clarified that a bit more. Thanks.